# python and MATLAB / Simulink

Tags: python, matlab, simulink

I made a simple python function that takes a list of numbers, increments all elements of the list and return the new list.
I'm trying call this function in simulink with a MATLAB Function block. It works when I give a single constant to the MATLAB Function but when I give a 1-N vector to the MATLAB Function, I got this error : Conversion of MATLAB 'double' to Python is only supported for 1-N vectors.
So my question is : how can I enter a vector in a MATLAB Function with python code inside ?

This is my python code

```
def add(array):
for i in range(len(array)):
    array[i] += 1
return array
```

This is the code of the MATLAB Function

```
    function y = fcn(u)
    y = 0; % Has to be preassigned, otherwise Simulink throws an error
    coder.extrinsic('py.test.add')
    y = py.test.add(u);
    end
```

This is the simulink model
[Simulink Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuzLb.png)